# Hide (or hard-code) choice parameter in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Sorry for my question, I'm new at jenkins, pipelines, groovy and other...
I have a task to disable choice parameter with only one choice in my jenkins job ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4hPC.png)
But if I comment it in groovy, my build fails. These parameters (loadEnvironment) is using in mainPipeline and may be in other places in checking.
I need only hide or hard-code it in my pipeline, not in main.

`properties([ parameters([ choice(choices: ['Stage2_new'], description: 'loadEnviroment', name: 'loadEnvironment'),`

Can you give me idea for this implementation? Thank you.

I tried to comment it - build fails

Comment: What error does the build fail with? Also, if there is only one choice and you need to disable it, why comment out the entire parameter block?

Comment: it uses in mainPipeline() and in several functions...
all other teams are using parameter with one choice, we want to disable it at Jenkins UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided it with comments of parameter (which I wanted to disable from UI Jenkins) in my pipeline and in main pipeline (which invokes by my pipeline). And in build of parameters I set loadEnviroment in default "stage 2" then map is empty.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities.

First you can add default parameter to your property attribute. Think the code in your case should look like this.

```
properties([ parameters([ choice(choices: ['Stage2_new'],defaultValue: 'whateverIsYourValue' description: 'loadEnviroment', name: 'loadEnvironment')
```

second solution is to use local variable (more like a global on script level) in which you will write property variable and use that local instead the parameter.

like:

```
def globalParam = ""
```

and then after you set the param

`globalParam = params.NAME_OF_PARAM_VARIABLE` in your case params.loadEnvironment

do whatever you want with globalParam .

Comment: Thanks for your help!
In first solution my defaultValue is 'Stage2_new', but will it display at Jenkins UI?

Comment: exist any type for doing it hidden? thanks!

Comment: It will display on ui no worries